# Does Pope Francis recommend giving communion under both kinds to the laity?

Tags: catholicism, communion, pope-francis

I've heard that Pope Francis recommends giving the communion under both species (i.e. the bread *and* the wine) to the laity, but I can not find proof of this. Is it true and could somebody provide official links to his recommendations?

Comment: @Geremina Actually hid does, you can find a lot of videos, e.g. https://youtu.be/AdH5c7nNMds?t=1m47s

Comment: I don't think he has actually expressed an opinion, at least as Pope.

Comment: Why wouldn't the pope endorse this?   Why do you need something from this pope when it's been a practice of the Roman Catholic Church to present the eucharist in both species for centuries?   Something seems to be missing from this question that would clarify why you find it important that the current pope did or didn't say something.

Comment: @KenGraham Here, I'll help * .... until the Middle Ages and especially Trent when a number of factors took the cup away from the laity until Vatican II and present legislation happily restored it*  Is "intinction" the point being asked about here?   Our question asker did not so specify, hence my "something's missing here" comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [General Instruction of the Roman Messal](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20030317_ordinamento-messale_en.html)

> It is most desirable that the faithful, just as the priest himself is
>   bound to do, receive the Lord’s Body from hosts consecrated at the
>   same Mass and that, in the instances when it is permitted, they
>   partake of the chalice (cf. no. 283), so that even by means of the
>   signs Communion will stand out more clearly as a participation in the
>   sacrifice actually being celebrated.[73]

This is not a recommendation from Pope Francis, but a valid option from the Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the Sacraments, so the Pope (obviously) approves it.

Communion under both species is most desiderable, but it often has some pratical difficulties in performing this option (OGMR 283).

> The diocesan Bishop may establish norms for Communion under both kinds
>   for his own diocese, which are also to be observed in churches of
>   religious and at celebrations with small groups. The diocesan Bishop
>   is also given the faculty to permit Communion under both kinds
>   whenever it may seem appropriate to the priest to whom, as its own
>   shepherd, a community has been entrusted, provided that the faithful
>   have been well instructed and there is no danger of profanation of the
>   Sacrament or of the rite’s becoming difficult because of the large
>   number of participants or some other reason.